# IBM MobileFirst Push Notification banner Android

Tags: android, push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst

We are using IBM Mobile First Push Notification V 7.1 and the issue that we are facing is unable to receive banner/badge push notification for android,when the application is active or in background.

However if I login into the application. I am able to the see the alert push notification. The Mobile First version is 7.1.

Please let me know how to resolve the issue when the application is in background or in foreground, I need to receive the banner notification.

Comment: Your question is not clear. If your application is in background do you see the notification appearing in the notification shade? What do you see in logcat?

Comment: No, i dont see in the shade, only when i login into the application , i see the notification alert.

Comment: Only if the application is killed i see the notification in the shade.

Comment: If the application is in foreground you will not see the notification in the shade. It will be routed to your application's push received callback. But you should see the notification in shade when it is in background. Have you customized your application in any way?

Comment: I have the IBM MobileFirst documentation for Push Notification and haven't customized any.

Comment: Can you provide a recreatable sample?

Comment: It is working fine now as i have missed to add a config file for the same.

Comment: Can you please add as answer what you missed adding and what you had to do to resolve the issue? This will help anyone looking to resolve such as issue